# How to make empty values available on data frame while writing to kafka on spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am getting one issue on writing my spark streaming dataframe to kafka. I am writing the dataframe as JSON structure. The following way am using to write

```
    val df =df_agg.select($"Country",$"plan",$"value")  
    df.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) AS value").writeStream.format("kafka").option("topic", "topicname").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "ddd.dl.uk.ddd.com:8002").option("sasl.kerberos.service.name","kafka").option("checkpointLocation", "/user/dddff/ddd/").option("kafka.security.protocol","SASL_PLAINTEXT").option("Partitioner.class","DefaultPartitioner").start().awaitTermination()
```

The issue is whenever my value for column "country" is empty , then its not even writting the field. For example i am getting dataframe df as

```
    US,postpaid,300
    CAN,prepaid,30
     ,postpaid,400
```

my output on kafka is

```
    {"country":"US","plan":postpaid,"value":300}
    {"country":"CAN","plan":0.0,"value":30}
    {"plan":postpaid,"value":400}
```

But my expected output is

```
    {"country":"US","plan":postpaid,"value":300}
    {"country":"CAN","plan":0.0,"value":30}
    {"country":"","plan":postpaid,"value":400}
```

How can i achieve this ? please help

Comment: This seems to be the default behavior of to_json. 
How about you write your own custom json encoder using something like spray so you can compare exactly what gets written out?

Comment: DO you have any examples for same ?